# How to disable SonarQube rule for code block in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I want to disable a block of code (a function) for a specific set of SonarQube rules (`javascript:S1541` and `javascript:S3776`) in a javascript file.

Any suggestions on how to do that?